# How to find the amplitude of a sine wave if only the time difference is known between consecutive appearance for a given vertical displacement value?

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing

If we know the values of a sine wave at $t_0$ and $t_1$, which we denote by $d_0$, is it possible to calculate the amplitude of that particular sine wave? We know only the difference $t_1 - t_0$, **not** the exact values of $t_0$ or $t_1$.

I am trying to find the amplitude of a sinusoidal vibration in a situation where the sensor can measure only the time difference $ t_1-t_0$ between consecutive threshold level of the vertical displacement $ d_0 $ being detected.

---

Here are my calculations. I get stuck when I get the $t_0 + t_1$ due to the fact I know only the difference $t_1 - t_0$.

$$ d_0 = A \sin (\omega t_0) \tag{1}$$

$$ d_0 = A \sin (\omega t_1) \tag{2}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$ 2 d_0 = A ( \sin (\omega t_0) + \sin (\omega t_1) )$$

and, thus,

$$ A = \frac{2d_0}{\sin(\omega t_0) + \sin(\omega t_1)} = \frac{d_0}{\sin\left(\omega \left(\dfrac{t_0 + t_1}{2}\right) \right) \cos\left(\omega\left(\dfrac{t_1 - t_0}{2}\right)\right)} $$

[image]

Comment: If the wave is $Asin(wt)$ can you write down two equations relating $A$ and $w$? Can you then relate those to trig expressions involving $t_1 - t_0$?

Comment: @Paul I honestly did try relate to the equations, 
but when I do so I get t1-t0 and a t1+t0 both terms. I only know the t1-t0 difference and not the exact t0 and t1, therefore I get stuck at what I could do to skip t1+t0 term.

Comment: @madu are phase and frequency known?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo frequency can be known. but better if I can resolve assuming if I don't know the frequency. and I do can make an assumption that phase is 0.

Comment: @madu Instead of adding, have you tried to subtract (2) from (1)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes yes indeed, I ended up with $$ t_0 + t_1 = \frac{\pi}{\omega} $$.  Substituting that to what I got by (1) + (2) I got a decent formula for finding A. Thanks.

Comment: @madu Are you sure?  That looks a bit too good to be true

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo,
when I do (1) - (2) I end up with, 
$$ 2\cos(\omega(\frac{t_0+t_1}{2})).\sin(\omega(\frac{t_0-t_1}{2})) = 0$$
since $$ t_0 \neq t  _1. $$ and $$\omega \neq 0$$,
we can say $$\sin(\omega(\frac{t_0-t_1}{2})) \neq 0$$
So that, 
$$ \cos(\omega(\frac{t_0+t_1}{2})) = 0 $$
$$ \omega(\frac{t_0+t_1}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
this gives 
$$ t_0+t_1 = \frac{\pi}{\omega} $$
hope I did it right...

Comment: @madu Do you have access to Mathematica or some other CAS?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes I have Matlab...

Comment: @madu I was thinking of symbolic computation.  MATLAB allows symbolic computation, but it's not nearly as good as Mathematica.  Ideally, you would post the code so that others could verify that your derivations are correct

Comment: Ohh thats cool. Never tried before, will try it on. thanks @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: @madu If you like Python, you can also try [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thats awesome, will try out that...